# "cvs copy" a file to create a new file

Tags: linux, shell, cvs

I have a file dir1/foo1 in CVS. I want to create a "cvs copy" of this file in CVS to dir1/foo2

I want to do this so as to retain the cvs history . (foo2 will only have a function defined in foo1)

can anyone please help with the command line syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read the manual:

Please, look at the [*Moving and Renaming Files*](http://ximbiot.com/cvs/wiki/CVS--Concurrent%20Versions%20System%20v1.12.12.1%3A%20Adding%2C%20removing%2C%20and%20renaming%20files%20and%20directories#SEC73) section.